# How to get string value of user id type <class 'str'> [facebook messenger bot]

Tags: python, django, postgresql, facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm creating facebook messenger app that is text based but does not require user to write specific commands.
I'm using python 3.6 and django 1.11.

The app asks for user's input and updates the phase that user has accomplished to database.

This system requires me to save user id to database and I have done that already. It works.

Instead.. when I try to create a database query it won't return any rows if I use the data from user's messenger message.

Here's how I create a record to database:

```
feedback_object, created = Feedback.objects.update_or_create(
                        source_created_at=feedback_start_at,
                        user_id=message['sender']['id'],
                        defaults={
                            'message': message['message']['text'],
                            'phase': feedback['phase']
                        }
```

Here's query that I CAN get the data from database:

```
r = Feedback.objects.filter(user_id='12345').latest('source_created_at')
```

Here's query that DOES NOT work but I need something similar:

```
r = Feedback.objects.filter(user_id=message['sender']['id']).latest('source_created_at')
```

Query doesn't return anything.

**Solution:** I went around this all by doing temporary db record that I can fetch and use in comparison with the original post.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, Django will convert as necessary. However OP has not actually said what is not working.

Comment: Last two rows say pretty clear what is not working.

Comment: No they don't. What exactly happens when you use that? Do you get an error? What does it say? If not what result do you get?

Comment: There was no error with the query because it just simply didn't return anything since information inside <class 'str'> didn't match user_id that was in the database. I added a go-around solution to the post though. And btw... post answers to "What is not working" but it does not answer "How is doesn't work".